# The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to add a css   form code .  My website uses a master page .  I am getting the error The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

my code snipet

```
string CssClass = string.Format("{0}/{1}?$BUILD$", BaseImageUrl, CssFileName);

HtmlLink css = new HtmlLink();
            css.Href = CssClass;
            css.Attributes["rel"] = "stylesheet";
            css.Attributes["type"] = "text/css";
            Header.Controls.Add(css);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't modify the `Controls` collection of the head tag, as the code in the header contains code blocks. So, you have two options:

- Remove the code blocks from the header and put the data in the header from code behind.
- Put a container inside the head tag (for example a `PlaceHolder`) and add the link to the `Controls` collection of the container.

Answer (score -1):

The error is because the control is not yet rendered, while the Javascript code is executed.

I just moved the javascript to the bottom of the page.