# The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have the folling code in my content page:
- masterpage
- strong type of masterpage
- ajaxcontroltoolkit

I think the error is caused by the fact that I have

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/dashboard/ProfMaster.master" %>
```

in the code. But I do not know how to solve it. I read some workaround like http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2006/May/27/The-Controls-collection-cannot-be-modified-because-the-control-contains-code-blocks-ie-
but that does not solve it.

Any ideas?

My
Code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/dashboard/ProfMaster.master" 
AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="profEditArticle.aspx.cs"      
Inherits="NoteBook.dashboard.profEditArticle" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor"
TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/dashboard/ProfMaster.master" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="CPHPROFRIGHT" runat="server">
    <cc1:Editor ID="Editor1" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Close duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825557/the-controls-collection-cannot-be-modified-because-the-control-contains-code-bloc

Comment: @Paul: it's not a duplicate/. I am not modifying any controls but still I get the error